# Need a workaround to get latitude and logitude values from fusedLocationProviderClient

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to put my markers on where my current location is but I can't extract the values of **this.latitude** and **this.longitude** from this

```
private double longitude, latitude;
private void getCurrLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(e-> {
            Location location = e.getResult();
                this.longitude = location.getLongitude();
                this.latitude = location.getLatitude();
        });
    }
```

and I'm trying to put those values in this code

```
        LocationButton.setOnClickListener(view -> new FetchURL(MapsActivity.this)
                .execute(getUrl(place1.getPosition(), place2.getPosition()), "driving"));

        place1 = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(this.latitude, this.longitude)).title("Location1");
        place2 = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(14.944777, 120.889943)).title("Location2");

        markerOptionsList.add(place1);
        markerOptionsList.add(place2);
```

Is there a way for me to extract those values?

Comment: i think you misunderstand what's happening there. you probably are setting those values, but it doesn't happen immediately, it is asynchronous, so something will get set to `this.longitude`, but it will happen at a later point in time. move all your code that you want to happen inside of your `addOnCompleteListener`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value/57330767#57330767

Comment: I tried moving them inside addOnCompleteListener and it didn't work. My debug prompted a "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation()' on a null object reference"

Comment: so then it's null and you should make sure that it isn't, right ? if (something != null)...

Comment: Do my latitude and longitude values come from the fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation()? If so, it shouldn't be null. I really apologize for this. I'm new at Java and I'm still trying to figure out what's going on,

Comment: What do you mean by you "can't"? What did you get? Also I don't see you actually calling `getCurrLocation()`

Comment: Is there a way for me to call getCurrLocation() and extract the values?